# Use latex math in coef names huxtable

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, quarto, huxtable

I am using quarto to generate an HTML report.
I have a regression table that I created using huxtable library.

I wanted to know how can I use math notation for the name of the coefficients.

here is the code for the table:

```
huxtable::huxreg(
    cox1,cox2,cox3,cox4,cox5,
    omit_coefs=factors,
    tidy_args = list(exponentiate = TRUE),
    coefs = c(
        "$Ln(capacity)$" = "log(plan_cap)", 
        "Government Owned" = "Owner_typeGovernment",
        "Noord-Holland" = "provinceN",
        "Zuid-Holland" = "provinceZ")
    )
```

However the results is:

[image]

What should I do in order to make the `Ln(capacity)` appear as math equation?

I need to know this since the rest of the tables I am going to produce include equations.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal and reproducible example of a quarto file. We do not know what are `cox1, cox2, cox3,cox4, cox5`. : }

Comment: Maybe the `set_escape_contents()` function could be halpful.